# Setting up Sentry with Django

Tags: django, docker, sentry

I installed Sentry with docker-compose

And I set up Django according to this manual 
https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/integrations/django/

But errors do not come in Sentry

I tested it:

```
python manage.py raven test
```

and got this result:

```
DEBUG 2017-12-26 08:49:51,033 base 67 140371587118848 Configuring Raven for host: 
Client configuration:
  base_url       : http://adyy.ru:9000/sentry
  project        : 2
  public_key     : 946327fca2844e8684d8233c89826062
  secret_key     : 96fb7bee962c413ba7356434c84985b1

Sending a test message... DEBUG 2017-12-26 08:49:51,305 base 67 140371587118848 Sending message of length 3464 to http://adyy.ru:9000/sentry/api/2/store/
Event ID was '28ca8194b1904081938fc2189cc3b7d2'
ERROR 2017-12-26 08:49:51,325 base 67 140371430176512 Sentry responded with an error: HTTP Error 403: OK (url: http://adyy.ru:9000/sentry/api/2/store/)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/raven/transport/threaded.py", line 165, in send_sync
    super(ThreadedHTTPTransport, self).send(url, data, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/raven/transport/http.py", line 43, in send
    ca_certs=self.ca_certs,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/raven/utils/http.py", line 66, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: OK
ERROR 2017-12-26 08:49:51,326 base 67 140371430176512 [u'This is a test message generated using ``raven test``']
```

what to do to make errors come in Sentry?